# Probability of both events happening

Tags: probability

Hello currently studying probabilities. I have to answer a question, I managed to answer the first part and i need help with the second part.

The question is

45% of the people in the shop bought at least one pack of snacks
70% of the people who bought at least one pack of snacks also bought some chocolate.

I managed to calculate the probability that randomly picked person bouth both items.

P(pack of snacks)=0.45
P(Pack of snacks and chocolate)=0.45*0.7=0.315=31.5%

Now the second part of a question is that additional information is given that 35% of people in the shop bought some chocolate. I need to calculate the probability of randomly picked person in the shop who bought chocolate also bought pack of snacks.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try seeing what happens if you have $200$ people coming to the shop.  For instance, $90$ people (of the $200$) bought snacks.  You may want to draw a Venn diagram to help sort things out.

Comment: Not familiar with Venn diagram, actually never heard of that.

Comment: You don't need to draw a Venn diagram.  But for this problem you'd draw two overlapping circles.  One circle for chocolate and one for snacks.  The people who bought both go into the overlapping region of the two circles.   Then there are regions for chocolate but no snacks; and snacks but no chocolate; and then outside of the two circles is for neither item purchased.  If you google Venn diagram you will find lots more info.

Comment: If i use 200 people in the shop, i get 15% probability of picking a person that did both purchases. Am i right ? If yes, how to shop the workings without Venn diagram?

Comment: From what you figured out in your main post, $31.5\%$ bought both.   That would amount to $63$ of the $200$ people.

Comment: Yes but the 31.5% is  for the first part where 70% of that 45% bought.... For the second part there is a new figure introduced (35% of whole population bought choco)

Comment: I assume that the information from the first part still holds; which would say that $35\%-31.5\%=3.5\%$ bought chocolate but not snacks.